# How does Gabriel–Ulmer duality extend to (limit, colimit) sketches?

Tags: ct.category-theory, duality, sketches

$\newcommand\Sketch{\mathit{Sketch}}\newcommand\Set{\mathit{Set}}
\DeclareMathOperator\Lim{Lim}\DeclareMathOperator\Colim{Colim}\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}\newcommand\mod{\operatorname{mod}}\DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}\DeclareMathOperator\Fun{Fun}
$Recall that a *sketch* $s = (\mathcal A_s, \mathcal L_s, \mathcal C_s)$ on a locally small category $\mathcal A_s$ comprises a collection $\mathcal L_s$ of small cones and a collection $\mathcal C_s$ of small cocones. A morphism $s \to t$ is a functor $A_s \to A_t$ carrying $\mathcal L_s$ to $\mathcal L_t$ and $\mathcal C_s$ to $\mathcal C_t$. We have a category, even a 2-category, $\Sketch$.

(I really do want to consider (limit, colimit) sketches and not just limit sketches here -- see the last bullet point below for an example of an interesting phenomenon which requires colimits in the sketches to see.)

Even better — there is a canonical symmetric monoidal closed structure on $\Sketch$ (so that $\Sketch$ is self-enriched). The unit is $i := (\ast, \emptyset, \emptyset)$. The tensor $s \otimes t$ is the coarsest sketch on $\mathcal A_s \times \mathcal A_t$ such that the functors $S \times (-) : \mathcal A_t \to \mathcal A_s \times \mathcal A_t \leftarrow \mathcal A_s : (-) \times T$ are sketch morphisms for $S \in \mathcal A_s, T \in \mathcal A_t$. The internal hom $\langle s, t \rangle$ is the sketch on $\Sketch(s,t)$ where $\lambda \in \mathcal L_{\langle s, t \rangle}$ iff $\lambda(-)(S) \in \mathcal L_t$ for any $S \in s$; $\mathcal C_{\langle s, t \rangle}$ is defined similarly.

A *model* of a sketch $s$ is a morphism $s \to d$ where $d:= (\Set, \Lim, \Colim)$. Write $\Mod(s) = \Sketch(s, d)$ for the category of models, and $\mod(s) = \langle s, d \rangle$ for the sketch of models. For any sketch $s$, there is a canonical sketch map $s \to \mod(\mod(s))$.

**Question 1:** When is the canonical map $s \to \mod(\mod(s))$ an equivalence?

**Question 2:** Is the canonical map $\mod(s) \to \mod(\mod(\mod(s)))$ always an equivalence?

**Question 3:** How do (1) and (2) look if we make everything in sight enriched in some nice symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal V$?

- For instance, $\mod(\mod(i))$ differs from $i$ only by adjoining absolute limits and colimits (it has an equivalent underlying category). We have $\mod(i) = \mod(\mod(\mod(i))) = d$, and $(d, \mod(\mod(i))$ are a dual pair under $\mod$.
- For instance, if $s = (C, \mathrm{finitelimit}, \emptyset)$ for some small, finitely-complete category $C$, then $\Mod(s) = (\Ind(C^\text{op}), \mathrm{limit}, \mathrm{filteredcolimit})$, and $\Mod(\Mod(s))$ differs from $s$ only by the addition of all absolute limits and colimits to the sketch. In particular, in this case we have $\mod(s) \simeq \mod(\mod(\mod(s)))$. Thus we basically recover Gabriel–Ulmer duality.
- If $s = (C, \emptyset, \emptyset)$ for some small category $C$, then $\mod(S) = (\Fun(C,\Set), \mathrm{limit}, \mathrm{colimit})$, and $\mod(\mod(s))$ is the idempotent completion of $C$, with just the absolute limits and colimits sketched, and again we have $\mod(s) \simeq \mod(\mod(\mod(s)))$.
- If we make everything additive, I believe that the sketch for a chain complex and the sketch for an exact chain complex are dual to each other under $\mod$ (the exact chain complex sketch is not just a limit sketch; it has colimits in it as well).

**Question 4:** Are there other interesting examples of dual pairs $s \simeq \mod(t)$, $t \simeq \mod(s)$?

**Question 5:** Is it always the case that $\mod(\mod(s))$ is obtained from $s$ by passing to the idempotent completion and adjoining absolute limits and colimits to the sketch, or can more interesting things happen as well?

Comment: Since the models of a sketch are the same as the models of an infinitary coherent theory coding the (co)limiting (co)cones, the duality theory can be understood by introducing the notion of k-pretopos representing the sketch, which would correspond to the syntactic side. Then one recovers a nice duality theory which makes the maps in questions 1 and 2 always equivalences. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: (if yes, I can post it as an answer detailing what are the morphisms on each side)

Comment: [A duality relative to a limit doctrine](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/10/20/10-20abs.html) gives a general answer to "To what extent can Gabriel–Ulmer duality be generalised to different classes of limits and colimits?". It's not in the terminology of sketches, but that should be a straightforward conversion. The enriched version will follow from [Accessibility and presentability in 2-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08710).

Comment: @godelian I think I’m talking about something a bit different because in my setting, mod(s) is not just a category but rather still has some cone/cocone information. But maybe that information is encoded somehow in the approach you describe?

Comment: @varkor I see what you mean in the context of limit sketches. But I really do want to allow colimits in my sketches, which would seem to make things more complicated.

Comment: I think you meant for the domain of $(-)\times T$ to be $A_S$. Nice question, this is the first time I’ve clicked the word ‘sketch’ and found something interesting!

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks, fixed! I agree, before today, really, I never really thought of sketches as anything more than an occasionally-convenient language. But the internal hom of sketches presents a kind of intriguing way to enhance the "semantic" category of models in a way which remembers something extra about the syntax of the "theory" presenting it. On the flip side, it might allow for extracting various "canonical" theories from a category of models which might be "smaller" than the sort of thing one tends to get from, say, ordinary Gabriel-Ulmer duality.

Comment: @TimCampion It is encoded, but for the duality I had in mind the morphisms should not necessarily preserve all of them but only some, so in that sense it's a bit different.